# Dynamically filter pk in queryset

Tags: django, filter

My generic DetailView:

```
class CircularDetail(DeleteView):
    model = Circular
    template_name = 'genre/circular_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(CircularDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['c'] = Circular.objects.get(pk=1)
        ctx['sittings'] = Sitting.objects.all()

        return ctx
```

My circular model:

```
class Circular(models.Model):
    cir_no = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    sit_start_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    sit_end_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parl_no = models.ForeignKey(Parliament,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('cir_no', 'sess_no',)
```

This only shows when pk=1 but I want to assign pk values dynamically so that when I chose different pk it gives corresponding data in view.

How can I assign pk values dynamically?

Comment: Assuming the view is actually based on DetailView, not DeleteView, what you want is what it does automatically; remove your definition of `c` and just access `object` in the template.

Comment: I am not clear from your reply. If I remove c what will be there. At present pk=1 is there which only return Circular No-1 not others. I want to get Circular No-2, 3, and so on

Comment: The whole point of a DetailView is that it is already responsible for populating the template context with the object associated with the pk. As I said, it is present as `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following and access object in template

sample url

```
url(r'^circular/(?P<pk>\d+)/details/$',
    CircularDetail.as_view(),
    name="circular_detail")
```

views

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class CircularDetail(DetailView):
    model = Circular
    template_name = 'genre/circular_detail.html'
```

in template.html

```
<div>
     CIR No: {{ object.cir_no }}
     Sit Start Date : {{ object.sit_start_date  }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers but my requirements is different. Here Cir no is related with sitting dates so each cir has different sittings.

Comment: Here is a link of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939288/change-scheduled-date-to-another-date-with-transfering-content-and-filter-pk-dyn. Of this question 1 is relevant now.

Comment: add   circular = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE) in your Sitting model then you can access different sittings in template with object.sitting_set.all

Comment: I did it using get_context_data @property decorators on sitting method

Comment: I don't think this answer fulfill my requirements